# Is there a function in Visual Studio Code that behaves the same as the `onDidChangeScrollTop` in Atom editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building a markdown preview extension for vscode, and I need to track the scrollTop position of the editor. I have looked through the vscode.d.ts file but I couldn't find any API.

What's more, is there a way to get the screen row of the editor. Right now I can only get the buffer row.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

No but here's the issue tracking exposing viewport information in the VSCode API: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/588

---

Also, as maintainer of VS Code's markdown extension, I'd be interested to know what features you feel the existing markdown preview lacks. There's a proposed API that would allow extensions to extend the builtin markdown preview: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22916 Perhaps this would be an easier way to achieve what you are after?

Feel free to [file an issue with more information about your use case](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) or [ping me on twitter](http://twitter.com/mattbierner)

Comment: Hi! I am trying to port an extension called **Markdown Preview Enhanced** that I wrote for [Atom editor](https://shd101wyy.github.io/markdown-preview-enhanced/#/) to vscode since some people ask for it. I just published a workable version on [visual studio marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced), and you can check it out if you are interested. I am trying to implement the automatic scroll sync in vscode, but I can't find related APIs. Therefore, I think I will just wait for the viewport API support then. Thanks!